# oauthPlugin.getAuthCredentials does not return anything

Tags: ionic

Am trying to solve the issue that is described here:

[Cannot find module 'forcejs'. while using angular 2 in ionic 2](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/130728/cannot-find-module-forcejs-while-using-angular-2-in-ionic-2)

Am trying to follow the solution that Kaushik Ray has provided but can only make it work in a browser. When runned inside android device its not working. I don't have any errors, am just not able to login to salesforce. This is my code:

inside forcejs

[image]

This is how i am calling forcejs from ionic 2:

[image]

this.contacts is empty and there is no errors. But when run with force-server I am able to fill this.contacts with data. Can anyone help me with this one?